# Php compare two table values with out two for each for code efficiency

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner in php, and so I need help understanding how to perform the task of comparing two tables which have a lot of records.

In user table I have:

```
id,
username,
phoneno,
city,
carddetails
```

and the other table has these columns:

```
id,
typeofthings,
typeofcard,
user_id(foreignkey).
```

I don't want to use a join in my query. I want to retrieve all the user data with its typeofthings to show.

How can I do this in single foreach? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you do want to put it in a join query.  That's what relational databases with foreign keys are for.

Comment: What you want does not make sense. If you don't join the tables or make a union between the rows of the two of them, you won't be able to traverse data with just one loop...

Comment: And if you are talking about "code efficiency," it will be a hundred times more efficient to join the tables than to do two separate queries and loop through the results of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this with a join.

Hands down. It will make your life much easier.

With join:

```
foreach($joined_data_row as $data) {
// do whatever you need to do.
 }
```

without:

```
foreach($user_in_table_one as $user) { 
// another query - 
$users_data = ORM::for_table("user_data")->where("user_id", $user['id'])->find_one();
//do what you need to do. You now have $user from the first table and $user_data from the second.
}
```

Now, that is bad, bad, bad, bad.
 You will fail your class -- you will be fired from your job. 
 Because you are making a query *for each row returned* 
Which is many times heavier of a load on the database! 
*I just handed you a noose, don't hang yourself with it*

With a join, however, you only *make one database query* -- which is much, much, much more efficient.

Now, since you're a beginner, I'll give you this tip: 
https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm

It will make your database functions much easier for you - including your join --

I know when I was a beginner, I hated MySQL until I came across that 
(We use propel, nowadays, however -- )

Comment: hi sir am a fresher thats y am asking like this,shall we use join queries for code efficieny?pls reply i can't understand

Comment: Well, as you are learning - you'll see time and time again that it is logical to organize related data in separate tables -- plus, smaller tables are more efficient in every aspect: MySQL speed, PHP simplicity, human-readability - as well as organizational benefits. 
However, multiple tables would mean more queries - So, assuming a query takes 100ms, you'd have to make a separate query for each table - In this example, you asked for *one* foreach loop - so that's what I gave you - but you could also (assuming no joins, still) do one foreach per table ---

Comment: So -- in my answer- I put another query inside of the loop - so foreach $result - it fires another 100ms query. If you had 100 rows, it would take 10 seconds to process the example in my answer! With two foreach loops, it would take 200ms  
BUT- with a JOIN statement, we can JOIN as many tables together as we need, and since MySQL treats the resulting JOIN as one table, the query only takes 100ms - (remember, we're assuming these times for simplicity) - The bottom line is, JOIN has virtually no impact on the MySQL's speed - so without joining the tables, you have to make a query for each table

Comment: Can I clarify further?

Comment: :yes am clear sir.in future how can i contact you can you please help me brother?

Comment: Oh, you can find me on G+ : jpope1089 -at- gmail -dot- com -- when I have time, I'll help how I can - and perhaps you can help me, too.